# SELECT statement WITH A WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please I am doing a where clause from a select query as below, can some help me with how I can add ----[CSI JOB] IS NULL OR >= '9/3/2010' AND to the where query. look at the query bellow

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM ABNESCCX
   WHERE SQL <> 'C' 
         AND [MYSQL] = 'B' OR [MYSQL] = 'D' 
         AND [CSI JOB] IS NULL 
         OR >= '9/3/2010' 
         AND [TNE TYPE] = 'Radio'
ORDER BY [TNE Completed];
```

Answer (score 3):

And you might also want to write [MYSQL] with parenthesis:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ABNESCCX
WHERE SQL <> 'C' 
 AND ([MYSQL] = 'B' OR [MYSQL] = 'D')
 AND ([CSI JOB] IS NULL OR [CSI JOB] >= '9/3/2010')
 AND [TNE TYPE] = 'Radio'
ORDER BY [TNE Completed];
```

Comment: +1 for giving a complete answer with a safer approach.

Comment: Mihai Bejenariu downvotes competitive answers. Don't worry, I upvoted yours so you don't lose the rep :)

Comment: @Alex there are many Mihai's on Stack Overflow. I don't know what he want to achieve by doing so.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the condition like that:

`([CSI JOB] IS NULL OR [CSI JOB] >= '9/3/2010') AND`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM ABNESCCX
WHERE
    [SQL] != 'C'
    AND [MYSQL] IN ('B', 'D')
    AND ([CSI JOB] IS NULL OR [CSI JOB] >= '9/3/2010')
    AND [TNE TYPE] = 'Radio'
ORDER BY [TNE Completed];
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers do I not need to use ISDATE for the date field in the clause?

Comment: What is the data type of CSI JOB column?